# Lookup field on custom form does not save once deployed on testing

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, form

I have a custom form on a content type I've created. This content type has 3 site columns which are a lookup field from 3 lists.
In the form I've created the user selects a dropdown box and chooses an item for each field. This fields are required.

It all works fine on my development machine, but it breaks down when I deploy it in testing.

I save the 4 list as templates and upload them on the new server, then I create the 4 corresponding lists. It all looks fine while adding a new item (the 3 fields correctly find the corresponding lists and present me the items to choose from).
After saving the item and opening up again every other field is filled but the 3 lookup fields.

No error is thrown while saving. It just skips the fields (which are required).

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't really say what the issue here is without a little more data.  Let's try some troubleshooting steps....

1. Verify whether the issue is with your forms or with your lists.  Try provisioning the lists without the custom forms.  Do they work as expected?  If so, then the issue is with the forms.  If not, your lists are to blame.
2. Assuming the forms are broken, how are you provisioning these forms?  Can you isolate which forms are broken and which ones are functional?

You're doing two pretty tricky things in a SharePoint solution - deploying lookup columns and provisioning custom forms.  It would be helpful to know more about your deployment approach.

Comment: I am happy to help.  You can benefit others with this issue by marking the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the were 2 problem cooperating against me with this issue.

1. First the list was not getting created properly (I call this a bug in sharepoint), the lookup columns did not work properly. If I tried to add them to the Item cotent type with the default form they did not properly get populated. I had to remove this columns, create them again on the new server and add them back to the content type. Not a great solution, but a working workaround.
2. The second problem was that 2 of the lookup fields (don't know why) ended up with and added '0' to their names, so they did not work after doing the steps on point 1, but worked on development. Fixing the name issues fixed the 2 lookup fields

Comment: Having similar problems - the content of lookup fields are lost upon deployment to another site/machine. From your answer I understood that you recreated lookup fields, correct? But have you managed to deploy to another machine/site without loosing content of lookup fields (I am having thousands items)?

Comment: saving the list from which I do the lookup as a template with content (there's a checkbox for that), I did not lose the content of the lookup fields and once I recreated them they worked properly